# Controling dynamic textboxes

Tags: vb.net

I want to make a program that adds 6 `TextBox` controls by clicking a button and then show the sum of 6 number in text boxes in a label.

I have written  code that adds text boxes but I have problem with their sum. How can I get all text boxes values?

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim txtn As Integer = 1
    Dim sum As Integer


    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        AddNewTextBox()
    End Sub
    Public Function AddNewTextBox() As TextBox 
        Dim txt As New TextBox()
        Controls.Add(txt)
        txt.Top = txtn * 25 
        txt.Left = 200           
        If txtn < 6 Then
            txtn = txtn + 1       
            Return txt
        Else
            MsgBox("sorry you reached the max number of text boxes")
        End If
    End Function

    Private Sub Label1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label1.Click
        Label1.Text =       'problem???
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: do you want sum of values of textboxes?

Comment: `For Each txtBox As TextBox In Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()` will allow you to reference to the `TextBox` controls. Place this in your `Label1_Click` method or wherever you deem fit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get a hold of a reference to the textboxes you are creating dynamically. You can do this by adding them to the list when you're creating them and then accessing them when you're summing up.

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim txtn As Integer = 1
    Dim sum As Integer

    Private _textboxesToSum As New List(Of TextBox)

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        AddNewTextBox()
    End Sub

    Public Function AddNewTextBox() As TextBox
        Dim txt As New TextBox()
        Controls.Add(txt)
        _textboxesToSum.Add(txt)
        txt.Top = txtn * 25
        txt.Left = 200
        If txtn < 6 Then
            txtn = txtn + 1
            Return txt
        Else
            MsgBox("sorry you reached the max number of text boxes")
        End If
    End Function

    Private Sub Label1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label1.Click
        Label1.Text = _textboxesToSum.Select(Of Integer)(Function(t) If(IsNumeric(t.Text), t.Text(), 0)).Sum()
    End Sub

End Class
```

You can also do it by iterating through all textboxes on your form, but you might have some other textboxes there, serving some other purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Before this make sure you validate `Texbox` input is numeric only

```
Private Sub Label1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label1.Click
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    For Each T As Textbox In Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()
        Try
            i = i + Val(t.text)
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

    Next
    Label1.Text = i
End Sub
```

loop updated...

Comment: Consider using `For Each T As TextBox In Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()` as currently it will loop through all the controls on the form which you don't want.

Comment: This will likely throw an `InvalidCastException`. Go with Jinx's solution.

Comment: thanks but can you explain this line (  Catch ex As Exception )

Comment: i have habit of try catch nothing else...
if you found this helpful you can vote up :P

Comment: @user7204131 the [Catch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk6t46tz.aspx)  _Provides a way to handle some or all possible errors that may occur in a given block of code, while still running code._ It's so you can handle them rather than an `UnhandledException` occurring causing the application to crash. They are useful at times and you should consider using them.